# replace the stdin for a file

Tags: stdin, scanf

I got a program with a fscanf like this:

fscanf(stdin, "%d %d,....

I got many fscanf and files that I'd like to test, the files are like this

10485770 15 51200000
 -2 10 
10 10485760 10485760
10 10485760 10485760
10 10485760 10485760

Well my question is how can I tell to the program or the compiler to take the inputs not from the keyboard, but from those files. These programs are benchmarks and in the files I got the inputs, I'm sure there is a way to do this automatic because in some case there are many inputs. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try freopen. Eg.

```
freopen( "somefile.txt", "r", stdin );
```

Answer (score 3):

When running from the command line, you can redirect a file to standard input using the '<' operator.

For example, on windows:

```
$ type input_file
10485770 15 51200000 -2 10 10 10485760 10485760 10 10485760 10485760 10 10485760
10485760
$ my_program.exe < input_file
```

Or on *nix:

```
$ cat input_file
10485770 15 51200000 -2 10 10 10485760 10485760 10 10485760 10485760 10 10485760
10485760
$ ./my_program < input_file
```

Answer (score -2):

Look up the FILE structure. You'll be wanting to use FILE pointers for this solution.

Comment: No - you won't be wanting to manipulate the innards of the FILE structure.  Treat FILE pointers as an opaque type; use them with the standard I/O library functions, or functions built atop those.  Do not poke around the insides of a FILE unless you are really sure you know what you are doing.